# Проверка значений на UPDATE в INSTEAD триггере MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, триггер

уважаемые

Есть таблица условно [table] с строковым полем [field].
Как написать триггер INSTEAD UPDATE, который бы 
1. проверял, является ли оно нулл ИЛИ в есть ли в нём проблемы
2. Если да, то дропал ошибку и НЕ вносил данные
3. Если нет, то заносил данные

Надеюсь, смог объяснить, Спасибо!

Comment: ну вы хоть посмотрели примеры подобных триггеров, сами то попробовали что-то сделать?

Comment: Да, я не очень понял, как обратиться к таблице inserted в условии

Comment: обратитесь к ней до условия. либо перепишите запрос с джойном, который будет исключать апдейт в случае чего, если такое возможно проверить в запросе. ну или еще что-то. поскольку мы не видим ваших попыток решить эту задачу и самих условий, то тут каике то гадания на кофейной гуще получаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, вам нужно использовать CHECK:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  MyField NVARCHAR(100),
  CONSTRAINT chk_T_MyField CHECK (MyField IS NOT NULL AND MyField NOT LIKE N'% %')
);
```

Таким образом, следующие INSERT'ы выдадут ошибки:

```
INSERT INTO T (MyField) VALUES ('Hello World');
INSERT INTO T (MyField) VALUES (NULL)
```

А это завершится удачей:

```
INSERT INTO T (MyField) VALUES ('Hello_World')
```

Comment: Ограничение не хочет работать на UPDATE. Я добавил ограничение, но изменить на значение с пробелом могу

Comment: Всё верно. Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо